# React - Render happening before data is returned and not updating component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, render, setstate

I can't get this to work correctly after several hours.

When creating a component that needs data from Firebase to display, the data is returning after all actions have taken place so my component isn't showing until pressing the button again which renders again and shows correctly.

Currently my function is finishing before `setState`, and `setState` is happening before the data returns.

I can get `setState` to happen when the data is returned by using the callback on setState but the component would have already rendered.

How do i get the component to render after the data has returned?

Or what would the correct approach be?

[image]

```
class CoffeeList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coffeeList: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.GetCoffeeList()
    }

    GetCoffeeList() {
        var cups = []
        coffeeCollection.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    cups.push({ name: doc.id})
            });
            console.log('Updating state')
            console.log(cups)
        })
        this.setState({ coffeeList: cups })
        console.log('End GetCoffeeList')
    }

    render() {
        const coffeeCups = this.state.coffeeList;
        console.log("Rendering component")
        return (
            <div className="coffee">
                <p> This is the Coffee Component</p>
                {coffeeCups.map((c) => {
                    return (
                        <CoffeeBox name={c.name} />
                    )
                })}
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the state before the promise is resolved. Change the code in the following way:

```
  GetCoffeeList() {
  coffeeCollection.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const cups = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
              cups.push({ name: doc.id})
      });
      console.log('Updating state')
      console.log(cups)
      this.setState({ coffeeList: cups })
      console.log('End GetCoffeeList')
  })
}
```